# Batik event listener

Tags: java, events, dom, svg, batik

I am trying to add an `event listener` to a `DOM  element`

```
Element image = svgDocument.createElementNS(Constants.SVG_NS, SVG_IMAGE_TAG);
                image.setAttributeNS(Constants.SVG_NAMESPACE_XLINK_URI, SVGConstants.XLINK_HREF_QNAME, "file:///" +  selectedDirectory.getPath());
                image.setAttributeNS(null, SVGConstants.SVG_X_ATTRIBUTE, Integer.toString(0));
                image.setAttributeNS(null, SVGConstants.SVG_Y_ATTRIBUTE, Integer.toString(0));
                image.setAttributeNS(null, SVGConstants.SVG_WIDTH_ATTRIBUTE, Integer.toString(150));
                image.setAttributeNS(null, SVGConstants.SVG_HEIGHT_ATTRIBUTE, Integer.toString(150));
                image.setAttributeNS(null, SVGConstants.SVG_HEIGHT_ATTRIBUTE, Integer.toString(150));

                // Listener
                ((EventTarget) image).addEventListener(
                        "click",
                        new org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void handleEvent(Event evt) {
                                System.out.println("listener");
                            }
                        }, false);

svgDocument.getRootElement().appendChild(image);
```

But it is not working at all.

Does someone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```
svgCanvas.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_INTERACTIVE);
```